# Presto SQL - Rank Multiple Conditions for Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to write a single query (if possible) to rank ids based on multiple conditions.

My table is like this:

```
id     group    subgroup  value
1      A        Q         12
2      A        Z         10
3      B        Z         14
4      A        Z         20
5      B        W         20
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN group = 'A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group ORDER BY SUM(value) DESC) AS rank_group
       CASE WHEN group = 'A' AND subgroup = 'Z' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group, subgroup ORDER BY SUM(value) DESC) AS rank_subgroup
FROM table
GROUP BY group, subgroup
```

But ended up with something like this:

```
id     rank_group    rank_subgroup
1      1             1
1      2             2
```

I would like to get each distinct id and return the rank based on the conditions of the case statement, but it looks like adding the needed partition causes a multiplication as the group by is necessary.  I could write individual queries for each column, but I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Edit your question and provide the results that you want.  What does ranking have to do with the `group by`?  The question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by sumg, group),
       dense_rank() over (partition by group order by sumsg, subg),
from (select t.*,
             sum(value) over (partition by group) as sumg,
             sum(value) over (partition by group, subgroup) as sumsg
      from t
     ) t;
```

This is my best guess at interpreting what you might want.

Comment: I would like to pass conditions within a case statement to create each column. 
However, with a case statement, the row_number is counted prior to the conditions being evaluated.  Therefore, I end up with columns with skipped counts like so:

    id     rank_group
    1      1                   
    2      2
    3      8
    4      9

Because (unlike a WHERE statement which evaluates prior to calculating any columns) a case statement will first calculate columns (the row_number in this case) then removes rows that do not match the condition.